# No internet on wlan then eth0 set to static

Tags: networking, internet, ifconfig, wlan

I am using rpi v3 so I have wlan as well. With this network config, when I am connected to wlan, I have internet access:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

With this one I dont (even though still connected to same wlan):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.10.10.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.10.10.5

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

What does eth0 have to do with anything here? Why does its configuration affect my lack of connection on wlan? I would appreciate all help really!

Comment: But thats not the case. Internet is obtained from wlan0, what does eth0 have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `gateway` entry under `eth0`. This adds a default route via `10.10.10.5`, which is not what you want if internet traffic is supposed to go through wlan0.